# setenv bash command not working in shell

Tags: linux, bash

I am trying to simplify my job by writing a bash file . 
When I try this code in Terminal :

```
env | grep $TMPDIR
```

it returns:

```
/tmp
```

( I don't know where this is set and couldn't find the line of code assigning this `/tmp` path to TMPDIR. I would be also great if someone can tell me how to find the file containing this assignment ).

Everything works fine when I set my correct path **in the Terminal** like this:

```
export TMPDIR=/My/Path/to/where/I/need
```

but it does not work when I use the same code in a bash file:

```
#!/bin/bash
setenv TMPDIR /My/Path/to/where/I/need
```

I also tried these:

```
setenv TMPDIR "/My/Path/to/where/I/need"
```

or:

```
export TMPDIR "/My/Path/to/where/I/need"
```

all of them return `"/tmp"` in response to `echo $TMPDIR`

Any suggestions?

Comment: `setenv` is for C shells, and sea shells are best left on the sea shore.  Why didn't you use `export` which works in the terminal inside the script?  What made you think you needed to change the command?  The `export TMPDIR` needs the `=` to assign the value; you can't have a variable called `/My/Path/…`.   What you type at the terminal is what you write in the script — give or take aliases, which is just another reason to avoid using aliases.

Answer (score 3):

`setenv` is for `csh` only. Use `export` in Bourne shells.

Unlike `csh`'s `setenv`, you need a `=` between the key and the value:

```
export TMPDIR="/My/Path/to/where/I/need"
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you are trying to run a shell script that sets an environment variable in the calling environment, as in:

```
$ echo $myvar
old_value
$ ./set_new_value.sh
$ echo $myvar
new_value
```

Firstly, you need to use export, not setenv.

Secondly, you need to source the script:

```
$ cat set_new_value.sh
export myvar='new_value'
$ source ./set_new_value.sh
$ echo $myvar
new_value
```

You can also use the . alone:

```
$ . ./set_new_value.sh
```

Cheers,
Holger